# SQL Server 2012 Management Studio no attach option for mdf files

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database, ssms

I am trying to attach a database to my Azure SQL using Management Studio 2012. However, there is no "Attach" option when I click on the `Databases` folder on the server. Could anyone make some suggestions how to attach a `.mdf` file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot attach an .mdf directly to Azure SQL Database. neither can you restore a backup (.bak).

you can follow what sqluser pointed out above.

there's also other options like using Migration Wizard, bacpac, etc...

have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee730904.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your database ==> Tasks ==> Deploy database to SQL Azure

[image]